# Managing Universal Xcode storyboards with version control

Tags: xcode, storyboard, ios-universal-app

An iPad application is already developed, which has to support iPhone version as well now. According to apple standards, we have to use size classes in order to achieve that. But I am confused how to manage the universal storyboard with version control(SVN), when working with a team. Different people has to work on the same storyboard. Can anyone give best approach to handle this case?

Comment: I did not catch your question, i use git, and my storyboard share across our team, what is your problem? SVN can't auto merge that file or something?

Comment: Now my team is divided in to two, one for iPhone and another for iPad. So there is a chance of getting conflicts when different people works on the size classes of same storyboard for managing the iPad and iPhone design.

Comment: @AliRiahipour did you get my question?

Comment: So your question is about merging the storyboard? I suggest using xib instead of storybord, because you can merge more easily across team

Comment: Please edit your question too, to add more about your merging problem